# Find the mimimum positive multiplicative path through an array

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming, path-finding, divide-and-conquer

I want to solve the following problem using a dynamic programming algorithm *(if possible)*:

Given a **square matrix/array A of non-negative integers** of any arbitrary size NxN, the objective is to find a path through that matrix from A[0,0] to A[N-1,N-1] such that:

1. The multiplication of all the numbers on that path is **minimal**, but,
2. The **path cannot contain any zeros**, as any zero will make the multiplication void.
3. The positions A[0, 0] and A[N-1, N-1] will always have value 1.

In short, the objective is to find a minimal multiplicative path through the array.

*For example:*

Given the following array:

[image: matrix]

The output should be the path shown in green, and the minimal multiplicative cost = 2

---

**My Efforts:**

I tried formulating it the same way the minimum additive cost problem is formulated but I cannot get around to solving the problem when the path is *not* monotonously descending, as in the example above where the path has to move up in the bottom row to reach the objective. I felt something like the A* algorithm might work but I'm not sure how to formulate the distance metric for that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Replacing 0 with max(A[i,j]) to the N²th power should do?

Comment: @greybeard Could you please elaborate? I don't see how that would solve the problem due to the path not being monotonously descending.

Comment: The replacement suggested should make just any path finding algorithm applicable: the product won't ever decrease. What is the problem with steps in opposite directions? (Please edit your question if an answer would improve it.)

Comment: There is no need to replace anything. Any standard graph algorithm will work. Just treat 0 as no edge.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, the given matrix can be treated as an adjacency matrix of a weighted graph! That's an useful tip! I was thrown off by the fact that most path-finding graph algorithms use additive cost, not multiplicative. Not sure if it's equivalent...

Comment: Multiplicative costs are equivalent to additive costs, just consider their logarithms.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. But wait! How would you formulate this into a graph? The matrix given is not symmetric and thus as an adjacency matrix can only represent a directed graph. Let's assume in the given example we had a 1 at the A[0,6] position. The required output should stay the same, i.e., 2. However, a path-finding algo on the graph will return the direct edge between 0 and 6 with cost 1. This is a trivial case but I think this will not work with a direct interpretation as an adjacency matrix. Any ideas on how to interpret the matrix to a suitable graph?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I guess we can intepret each value in the matrix as a weight on a undirected graph with NxN vertices, and solve from there. Building the adjancency matrix for that graph will be O(N^4) in space complexity. I was hoping for a more effcient solution.

Comment: Why would you need to build an adjacency matrix? A graph can be represented in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

We can run Dijkstra, where the visited set stores directed edges instead of vertices. (There are `O(n)` directed edges in our case since each node can be a target of at most 4 directed edges.)

Python example:

```py
import heapq

def get_neighbours(i, j):
  return [(i+1, j), (i-1, j), (i, j+1), (i, j-1)]

def is_valid(M, i, j):
  return i >= 0 and i < len(M) and j >= 0 and j < len(M[0]) and M[i][j] != 0

def f(matrix):
  n = len(matrix)
  queue = [(matrix[0][0], (0,0,0,0), [(0,0)])]
  min_cost = {(0,0,0,0): matrix[0][0]}
  visited = set([(0,1,0,0), (1,0,0,0)])

  while queue:
    total_cost, edge, path = heapq.heappop(queue)
    ii, jj, i, j = edge

    if (i, j) == (n - 1, n - 1):
      return total_cost, path

    visited.add(edge)

    for y, x in get_neighbours(i, j):
      new_edge = (i, j, y, x)
      if new_edge in visited or not is_valid(matrix, y, x):
        continue

      new_cost = total_cost * matrix[y][x]

      if not new_edge in min_cost or new_cost < min_cost[new_edge]:
        min_cost[new_edge] = new_cost
        heapq.heappush(queue, (new_cost, new_edge, path + [(y, x)]))

  return float('inf'), []
```

Output:

```py
m = [
  [1,7,7,7,7,7,7],
  [1,7,7,7,7,7,7],
  [1,7,7,7,7,7,7],
  [1,7,7,7,7,7,7],
  [1,7,1,1,1,7,7],
  [1,7,1,0,1,7,7],
  [1,1,1,0,2,1,1]
]

print(f(m))

# (2, [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0),
#      (5, 0), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (5, 2),
#      (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4),
#      (6, 5), (6, 6)])
```